# Why does Python transform exact decimals to approximations in calculations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

I wrote this function to avoir typing on a calculator and make my homework faster but something very strange happened :

```
def G(x):
  return 1 - x ** 2 - (1-x) ** 2
```

G(1/5) gives 0.31999999999999984

But it is clearly 25/25 - 1/25 - 16/25 with is 8/25 = 0.32

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems

Comment: I get it now ! Thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module as a workaround.

> The decimal module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic. It offers several advantages over the float datatype.

```
from decimal import Decimal;

print(float(G(Decimal(1)/Decimal(5))))
0.32
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank you !